# How to replace global keyboard presses on macOS in Delphi with FireMonkey?

Tags: macos, delphi, keyboard, firemonkey

**I'd like to build a Delphi FireMonkey application for macOS that can detect when I press 2-4 keys simultaneously, and then replace them with a full word.**

For example, when I press P + E together, I'd like the active application to ignore the P  + E and instead receive the key presses for the word 'people'.

If somebody can help me with **a simple example in Delphi/FireMonkey for macOS** that captures all keys on the keyboard and replaces them with some random keys, that would be amazing.

I haven't been able to find a simple example for capturing keys in Delphi/macOS and am now trying to find my way in the forest of `Quartz Event Services`, `Macapi.CoreGraphics`, `Macapi.IOKit`, and `TNSNotificationCenter`, but I'm completely stuck.

I plan for this application to stay active with a Menu Icon, so I guess I don't need a daemon or anything fancier. And I'm happy to grant Input Monitoring privileges to the app.

(I've set up this functionality in Karabiner Elements, but the config of that app is too slow. It also doesn't do exactly what I want. And I'd like to be able to debug this functionality myself.)

Thanks!

Comment: I expect you may need to use something like [`addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1534971-addlocalmonitorforeventsmatching?language=objc) with a mask combining `NSEventTypeKeyDown` and `NSEventTypeKeyUp`, and track `event.keyCode` for each event, checking for when `NSEventTypeKeyDown` events occur for the relevant keys without a corresponding `NSEventTypeKeyUp`. I also expect it may not be trivial since for one thing, `addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask` was not imported into `Macapi.AppKit` for `NSEventClass`.

Comment: Thanks, @DaveNottage. That sounds bad 

I wonder if there's a compiler/translator that can automatically translate definitions (like the one for `addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask`) to Pascal? I remember we did stuff like that for Windows, many years ago.

Otherwise, I guess may have to hire somebody on UpWork to figure this out for me  

Thanks for your input! Appreciate it very much.

Comment: I've pushed a change to [this unit](https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/blob/master/API/DW.Macapi.AppKit.pas) to include an import for NSEvent that includes all methods. If you're still having trouble, send me an email to: davidn at radsoft dot com dot au, and I'll see if we can work something out :-)

Comment: Wow, @DaveNottage, thank you so much! You're a gentleman  

And yes, I'll keep your address around for when I need help with this. Have a great day 